# Посимвольное разделение строки и добавление в словарь

Tags: c#, словари

Есть словарь:

```
Dictionary<string, string> all = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Каким образом можно разделить считываемый файл построчно и каждую строку на символы и добавить в словарь, что бы потом в дальнейшем обращаться к нему по типу --> all.ff1[1].Values, all.ff2[1].Values

Считываемый файл выглядит вот так:

- QT
- AM
- AW
- TE
- CQ
- ME
- IG

---

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Select( new { ff1 = 
Convert.ToString(filename[0]), ff2 = Convert.ToString(filename[1]) });

foreach (var line in lines)
   {
       all.Add(line.ff1, line.ff2);
   }
```

Comment: Извините, но что за бред вы тут понаписали? `разделить считываемый файл посимвольно в строке` - так "посимвольно" или построчно и каждую строку на символы? `line.ff1[1],line.ff2[1]` - а как вы собираетесь так обращаться к словарю? Словарь это `string value = all["MySuperKey"];`, а ваш вариант написания вообще мало подо что подходит в C#. Хорошо, что такое `line`, что такое `ff*`, что за индекс (`[1]`)?

Comment: Хорошо не так написал немного, обращаться примерно так all.ff2[1].Values

Comment: Ок, уже лучше, зачем тогда вам тут словарь? Что должно быть ключом, а что должно быть значением? Вот вы ей богу, можете не как в детском саду ребенок объяснять, а нормально, по человечески объяснить нам всю задачу, ведь это же в ваших интересах!

Comment: Ключ не нужен, можно индексом обойтись, в словаре должно хранится 2 значение например (Q,T)

Comment: Ну раз не нужен ключ, зачем тогда `Dictionary`? Хорошо, тогда вот: `var result = File.ReadAllLines("superFile").Select(x=>x.ToCharArray());`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ что посоветуете лучше использовать если не Dictionary ?

Comment: Я вам уже дал решение вашей задачи. Будет простая коллекция `IEnumerable<char[]>`, в коллекции будет массив из символов строки (`char[]`). Дальше уже используйте как вам надо, например цикл: `foreach (var arr in result) Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);` Ну или преобразуйте это в `List<char[]>` (дописав в конце `.ToList()`) и используйте как хотели по индексу: `Console.WriteLine(result[0][0]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Разделение `string` на массива строк по символу возврата строки

```
string[] lineArray = text.Split(new [] {'\r', '\n'});
```

Преобразование `string` в массив символов

```
char[] charArray = lineArray[0].ToCharArray();
```